# WinError 2: The system cannot find the file specified: (Cannot set explicit path to .exe file)

Tags: python, exe, executable

I am attempting to use the package WhiteboxTools. I have installed it to my python environment and imported it to my Jupyter notebook script. The whitebox documentation suggests explicitly setting the path to the executable file if it is not in the same folder as the script being written with the following:

```
wbt.set_whitebox_dir('/local/path/to/whitebox/binary/')
```

Another reason I believe this to be the problem is that I set the path to this file in my first code chunk: `wbt.set_whitebox_dir('C:\\Users\\maxduso.stu\\Anaconda3\\envs\\geo\\pkgs\\whitebox_tools-2.2.0-py39hf21820d_2\\Library\\bin\\whitebox_tools.exe')`, but the error arises in the next code chunk which calls one of the tools:

```
wbt.breach_depressions_least_cost(
    "C:\\Users\\maxduso.stu\\Desktop\\FCOR_599\\project_work\\data\\tif_folder\\full_pa.tif", 
    "C:\\Users\\maxduso.stu\\Desktop\\FCOR_599\\project_work\\data\\tif_folder\\sa_breached_dem.tif", 
    dist = 10,                         #maximum search distancefor breach paths in cells
    max_cost=None, 
    min_dist=True, 
    flat_increment=None, 
    fill=True
)

[WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\maxduso.stu\\Anaconda3\\envs\\geo\\pkgs\\whitebox_tools-2.2.0-py39hf21820d_2\\Library\\bin\\whitebox_tools.exe'
```

`whitebox_tools` is one of two files I attempted, the other being `whitebox_gui`. These files were suggested to me when I searched for ".exe" in the whitebox tools folder within my environment folder. That said, they are type = Application and so that brings me to the question: why did windows autofill "whitebox_tools.exe" in the file search bar but find an application file? Also, considering I cannot find a file of type .exe, where do I go from here?

Note: the tools also don't run without the path set.

Thanks for reading. I hope the question was clear enough.

Comment: `whitebox_tools.exe` is a file, `wbt.set_whitebox_dir` implies set a directory.  Try removing `\\whitebox_tools.exe` from the end bit of that argument to set an actual directory that would contain the tool.

Comment: You could make sure that the directory is correct by checking `import os;print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: @metatoaster you are absolutely right that was exactly the problem. Oops, I feel stupid now.